# remove all images of a cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove images from a cloned div.

I tried this:

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
var clonedDiv = jQuery.extend(true, {}, divToPrint)
var images = [].slice.call(clonedDiv.getElementsByTagName('img'), 0);
var l = images.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]);
}
```

This line is wrong, I don't know how to get all images of the cloned div:

```
var images = [].slice.call(clonedDiv.getElementsByTagName('img'), 0);
```

I get  this error:

```
'getElementsByTagName' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how you clone an element:

> ```
> var clonedDiv = jQuery.extend(true, {}, divToPrint)
> ```

This is how you clone an element with the DOM ([`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)):

```
var clonedDiv = divToPrint.cloneNode(true);
```

Then to find the `img` elements within the clone (with the DOM):

```
var images = clonedDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

To remove them (with the DOM's [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)):

```
while (images.length) {
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
```

The NodeList returned by `getElementsByTagName` is live, so the image will disappear from the list, putting a new one at index 0, so that removes images one by one until they're all removed. If you might have a polyfilled `getElementsByTagName` (but that's unlikely) that doesn't do that, just loop in reverse order instead:

```
for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    images[i].parentNode.removeChild(images[i]);
}
```

---

Or all of that with jQuery ([`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)):

```
var clonedDiv = jQuery(divToPrint).clone();
clonedDiv.find("img").remove();
```